# A very bizarre confusion

Tags: unit-of-measure

This is a maths problem I am not sure, but I know that normal paper money is approximately $1\text{mm}$ thick. But why is there $100$ notes in a $1\text{cm}$ thick paper money stacked in say banks? Wouldn't $1\text{mm}$ thick paper money imply that $1\text{cm}$ should be $10$ paper money stacked on top of each other? What am I missing here?

(This is not a random question, I genuinely do not know why this is the case and I have no suitable place to ask at this point in time).

Comment: Not sure I get the question, but a dollar bill is about [$.11$ mm thick](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/1999/DeneneWilliams.shtml).

Comment: Ok never-mind, my mistake I have mistaken the dollar bill's thickness as $0.043 $inches, not $0.0043$inches. My bad ...